# Рисование в UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, uwp

Столкнулся с проблемой реализации UI. Есть задача: реализовать что-то на подобии UML редактора, в котором бы существовала всего одна кликабельная фигура, которую можно было бы создавать бесконечно много на странице, с возможностью передвижения Drag-and-Drop по всей странице. При этом, между фигурами можно проводить линии, которые бы подстраивались под новые координаты фигур при изменении их положения на странице.

Подскажите, в какую сторону капать? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вы уже хоть что-нибудь попробовали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, нашел статью на Metanit'е, посвященную рисованию в UWP, и попытался реализовать с использованием Ellipse и Line на Canvas. Но как-то не очень получилось, да и координаты жестко закодированные получаются. А нужно Drag-n-Drop ещё привязывать. Поэтому ищу что-то похожее на мою задачу, что бы узнать, как сделать лучше и проще. Возможно даже есть готовые решения для работы с графикой, но я таких не нашел.